# DIY Lighting for Macro Photography

Tags: lighting, macro, diy

I am using a simple reversal ring to mess around with macro photography at my home. My question is this what is the best way to light shots for macro photography?

A Few Notes:

- I am photographing stationary objects.
- I am looking for cheap Do It Yourself Methods
- I am *not* looking to buy a [macro flash](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18738/what-are-options-for-macro-lighting).
- I have only the built in flash, no external flashes.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18738/what-are-options-for-macro-lighting

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I don't think it's a duplicate since this question is asking about a DIY technique, also Lynda states that she ain't buying a macro flash, so I believe the high cost of macro flashes is to be considered here

Comment: @AkramMellice - You are right, the cost of macro flashes (400+ on Amazon) is prohibitive and not a consideration here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it's not a DIY, the [NEEWER® Macro Ring LED](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0031AQ302) is considered to be cheap (around $30). I tried myself with my extension tube, not bad at all. It provides constant light which is essential if you are too close to the subject. You can mount the power supply for it in your camera's hot shoe, you can use either 4 AA batteries or plug it directly.

If you want to *Do It Yourself* for the sake of fun, check [this](http://www.diyphotography.net/diy-macro-lighting-led-ring) but it will cost you around $20

Comment: For $30? I'd buy the thing, even if it isn't that powerful, as it'll match, or exceed, any DIY option for almost the same price. I probably would have bought that if it had been around, but I've since dropped my coin on the Metz ringflash.

Comment: That is an interesting Light. The only issue is I am using a reversal ring (aka lens is on backwards) and would have to rig up something to hold the light but I like the idea. =>

Answer (score 3):

Make a tent of white cloth (cheap bed sheet) over the object. Have one smallish hole for your camera lens. Use a couple of lights outside the tent. Doesn't matter much what kinds of lights, but they should be the same type (tungsten, fluorescent, halogen, etc.)

Make something that looks like this commercial product:
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/386545-REG/Impact_DLS_XL_Digital_Light_Shed.html

Use a tripod and you can use slow shutter speeds to make up for the dim light.

Comment: for small object you can replace the tent by a milk galon